# Codeigniter files on web host/server

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have trouble understanding this line on CI's installation instruction, what does web root excatly mean? it says that for better security, system and application should be above web root, does this mean that, like in a web host, this should be above public_html? or inside public_html? e.g public_html/system and public_html/application.. or in the case of a local server like XAMPP, inside htdocs? like htdocs/system and htdocs/application? i am really confused when it says above web root. cuz if i think of it, it will be outside public_html or outside htdocs. Please do enlighten me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
. /
.. /
public_ftp /
public_html /
application /
system /
```

This will put `application` and `system` ABOVE the webroot which is `public_html`

Comment: so you mean to say application and system is on the same level as public_ftp / and public_html / ??

Comment: Yes, `public_html` is the webroot as it is what is accessible by the browser as `/` a user cannot traverse higher than `/` thus they are limited to content within `public_html` and thus cannot access contents above it or in the same folder it resides in.

Comment: so that being said, how do i access CI when in fact public_html is your root, relating it to a domain name like example.com = public_html how can i access CI then?

Comment: You should be accessing CI by accessing `index.php` which would be kept in `public_html` if you open that file you can see config options to specify the location of `system` and `application` set them to the location where you moved them (outside of `public_html`) and you're good to go.

Comment: ohh like ../system and ../application? is that what you mean to say?

Comment: Inside `index.php` you have the following `$system_path = '/full/path/to/folder/outside/of/webroot/system';` and `$application_folder = '/full/path/to/folder/outside/of/webroot/application';` Where the `system` and `application` folders are IN the SAME directory that `public_html` is in. Technically you can move the folders anywhere in your filesystem so long as you put the correct path in the above two settings, just make sure you *don't* put them inside `public_html` as that defeats the security you are trying to do.

Comment: isn't using absolute path not recommended? i mean instead of using the abosulute path, can i use ../system? 1 folder up?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24577/discussion-between-cryptic--and-lemoncodes)

Answer (score 0):

no, above public_html,

So if /home/lemoncodes/public_html is your WWW folder, you should put your files in:
/home/lemoncodes.

Comment: you're conflicting yourself. You say under public_html, then tell him to put the files on the same level as public_html

Comment: @RickCalder If you look at a tree, the root is on the bottom of the tree, so yo if go down one folder, you go down, so the folder is under the other folder. Well, that how i see it, and I guess my example tells the story well enough.

Comment: Your example is wrong. It should read /users/lemoncodes/public_html

Comment: @rickcalder No, it is correct, /home/lemoncodes/public_html is the folder you want to avoid for putting your system folders in. It should be up one level, so in /home/lemoncodes. You were right about the folder structure, it should be called UP one folder, my view of a tree s incorrect, it should be a tree upside down ;-))

Comment: depends entirely on the host, my host won't allow me to point to folders outside the public_html

Comment: @rickcalder A simple explanation: Your system files go one folder lower, so it cannot be accessed from outside, only index.php and files that should be public  (images/css/js) are in the public folder. This makes it a little bit more secure (example: php parser stops working, if you files are in the public folder, everyone can see your connection files, if you put it a folder lower, they can only access index.php, and not your system files). Some hosters block this with open_basedir for some reason, but most dont (if they do, just call them).

Answer (score 0):

If you consider that the representation of a directory and sub​​-directories is a tree, we will soon see that it refers to the following:

```
. /
.. /
public_ftp /
public_html /
| - Application /
| - System /
etc.
```

Soon Aplicattion and System folder should be inside public_html.

Comment: This does not put application and system above the webroot it puts it inside which defeats the security aspect.

Answer (score 0):

In web server the root is public_html/system and public_html/application that means the public_html refers to the your domain name .

In local htdocs/domain/system and htdocs/domain/applications

Comment: in short, system and application is placed under public_html? and public_html is your web root right? so why does CI ask me to put it ABOVE web root? does this mean that it is outside public_html???

Comment: For which purpose CI ask ABOVE web root?

Answer (score 0):

Webserver with single website:
The files should go wherever your server tells you the web root is, in most server scenarios this is public_html so as Arthur Barros illustrated.

Webserver with multiple sites:
In this scenario the common way of doing things is for each site to have it's own folder inside of public_html. In this case the web server is set up for each domain to have it's own folder, so that domains folder becomes the web root. So as below

```
public_html
...WebSite1
...WebSite2
......Application
......System
...WebSite3
```

XAMPP:
I strongly suggest setting up CI in XAMPP the way I explained you would set it up in a webserver with multiple sites. While it technically would work in the htdocs folder directly it's not a good idea in my opinion. Create a folder inside htdocs for your site then access it via that folder in the web browers.

```
htdocs
...myWebsite
......Application
......System

http://localhost/myWebsite would be your base url.
```

Even on a web host with a single website it still makes sense to contain CI in it's own folder, the adjust your htaccess, config and routing files to point to that folder. So your site could actually reside in www.example.com/my_website but you set up your files so you would point to www.example.com or www.example.com/contact.

This just keeps things compartmentalized, and allows you to install other things, other CI applications etc on the server without conflicting with your original install.

Comment: hmmm i get your point but why is CI telling me to put it outside the web root? it says ABOVE web root? i know its for security reasons but whats the point in putting it above your webroot where no one can access your site?

Comment: Honestly I never read that in CI's documentation. For the record it will work if your webhost supports symlinks. You create a folder outside the Public_html and symlink to it from inside the public_html but we found that caused headaches with our host since we couldn't point a specific domain at a symlink.